# ajax call to update jade partial template

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm having trouble when I update a div content with a partial jade template. The first ajax call to delete user works fine and div content is updated, but when I click again to delete others user, the ajax action is not called. I cannot see where is the problem.

This is my code

**view/layout.jade**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    .container
        block content
    block footer
      script(type='text/javascript' src='/javascripts/jquery.min.js')
      script(type='text/javascript' src='/javascripts/functions.js')
```

**view/index.jade**

```
extends layout

block content   
    include menu.jade
    #users_list
        include users.jade
```

**view/users.jade**

```
table
    thead
      tr
        th Id
        th Name
        th Description
        th(colspan='2') Actions
    tbody
      if(users)
        each user in users
          tr
            td #{user.id}
            td 
              a(id=user.id href='#') #{user.name}
            td                  
              a(id=user.id href='#') #{user.description}
            td
              a(class='user_edit' id=user.id href='#' ) 
                img(id=user.id src="images/edit.png")
            td
              a(class='user_delete' id=user.id href='#') 
                img(id=user.name src="images/trash.png")
```

**routes/index.js**

```
router.get('/deleteUser/:userid', function (req, res) {

    UserModel.deleteUser({userid: req.params.userid}, function(error, data){        
        res.render('users', {          
            users : data
        });
    });
});
```

**javascripts/functions.js**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    //others functions and variables here!!!!!

    $('.user_delete').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var userid = $(this).attr('id');    
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: baseurl + 'deleteUser/'+userid,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){
                $('#users_list').html(data);
             },
         });
     });
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you bind the event handler to elements already rendered in the web page. When you click delete and trigger the event handler, all those elements are removed from the page and replaced with the new content, in:

```
success: function(data){
    $('#users_list').html(data);
},
```

The easiest solution is to bind the event handler to an element which you know will still be on the page, and use the `selector` argument to `on` to filter for the elements you wish to bind to. This event handler will be bound to the parent element which you never remove from the page. When you click a delete link, the event will bubble up to that element and, since it matches the selector, the event will trigger. For example:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.user_delete', function(e) {
    // as before...
}
```

As an added bonus, this may be slightly more performant in the browser since you only bind one event handler to one element, instead of many (I'm not quite sure about this in recent versions of jQuery, but I think it still holds true).

That said, you absolutely **do not** want to have a destructive action in a `GET` request. This is a sure way of destroying data. `GET` is meant for getting data, and always getting the same data for the same request. Use a `POST` request for this, or even better, a `DELETE` request.

Comment: thanks for the rapid response. I'll try that solution...damn "copy & paste" for the 'GET' action.